Why my scrollbar in Instagram doesn't work?
I'm working on a Instagram autosub project. It's a dynamic website, so I would need to scroll down. I know how to do this in the MAIN window, but since Interest are a pop-up window this solution to scroll doesn't work.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

chrome_option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_option.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_option)
driver.get(url="https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login")

USER = "USER"
EMAIL = ("EMAIL")
PASSWORD = "PASSWORD"

try:
    cookies = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Allow all cookies')]"))
    )
    cookies.click()

    enter_email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value='//input[@name="username"]')
    enter_email.send_keys(EMAIL)

    enter_password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value='//input[@name="password"]')
    enter_password.send_keys(PASSWORD)
    enter_password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    not_now = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div ._ac8f div"))
    )
    not_now.click()

    not_now2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Not Now")]'))
    )
    not_now2.click()

    driver.get(url=f"https://www.instagram.com/{USER}/")

    follows = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, '/following')]"))
    )
    follows.click()

    fBody = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]']")
    scroll = 0
    while scroll < 5:
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', fBody)
        time.sleep(2)
        scroll += 1

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

I've looked at stachoverflow, asked the GPT chat, looked at a bunch of videos, but nothing's helped.
Selenium Python: How to Scroll Down in a Pop Up window
Why scroll on modal/popup doesn't working on instagram
Even these didn't help.
Could it be just a problem with this version of Instagram?

How Instagram is a infinite feed, you could use the scroll to render all the info you need. Wait it loads, and get the info you need.
Like:
while scroll<5:
    element=""
    try:
        time.sleep(5)
        element=drive.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"fbody")
    except: # The exception you want to put
        print("Not find")
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        scroll+=1
    else:
        if(element="")
             driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
             scroll+=1
        else:
             break

